# В html странице выводятся знаки вопрос вместо русских букв

Tags: java, html, intellij-idea, tomcat

Здраствуйте, помогите пожалуйста если кто знает в чём дело. Перепробовал уже всё что нашёл в интернете но пока безрезультатно.
Почему то при запуске проекта в Idea на странице отображаются знаки вопроса вместо русских букв

Что я уже попробовал:

1. Убедился что консоль в ответ на запрос выдаёт 866
2. Также в параметрах регионального стандарта, во вкладке дополнительно я нажал кнопку **"изменить язык системы"**
   и там снял галку с параметра **"Бета-версия: Использовать Юникод (UTF-8) для поддержки языка во всем мире."** Сохранил и перезагрузил.
3. В фалйах **idea.exe.vmoptions** и **idea64.exe.vmoptions** Добавил следующую строку:
   **-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8**

Так же добавил её в редакторе **Idea > EditConfigurations > Tomcat > VM options**
Так же добавил её в редакторе **Idea > Help > Edit Custom VM Options**

4. Так же в настройках **File > Settings > FileEncodings** выставил
   Global Encoding в UTF-8
   Project Encoding в UTF-8
   Default encoding for project files: UTF-8
   Create UTF-8 files with NO BOOM
5. В правом нижнем углу редактора так же выставил UTF-8
6. Проверил что в хедере моего index.html который я пытаюсь отобразить стоит `<meta charset="UTF-8">`
7. Так же пересохранил на всякий случай мой index.html с помощью блокнота с кодировкой UTF-8
8. Запустил саму страницу index.html двойным кликом в папке и она нормально отображает кнопку с руским языком, а так же тестовый текст с русским языком.
   однако когда я нажимаю в idea кнопку run Tomcat почему то страница показывает знаки вопроса вместо русских букв

Comment: А откуда страница берется? Просто открываете в IDEA? Или у вас сервер ее такой возвращает? Если с сервера, то я бы посмотрел что возвращается в заголовке HTTP: `content-type`. Там кодировка указывается, например `text/html; charset=utf-8`. Еще хорошо бы в HTML тег meta в таком виде оставить: `<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>`

Comment: @gil9red
Да вы правы. В HTTP: content-type у меня text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1 
Сервер tomkat. Сайт работает на нём. Нашёл инструкцию по его настройке сейчас мучаюсь с ней
https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-utf-8

Comment: @gil9red Указал в html тег в таком виде как высказали
Сделал как написано тут. https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-utf-8
Однако изменений это не дало. content-type так и отсылается на страницу в виде
text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1